# Parsing XML Inner XML tags Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, parsing

I would like to create an NSDictionary or (NSArray) full of NSDictionary objects for each station in the following XML:

```
<stations lastUpdate="1328986911319" version="2.0">
    <station>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>River Street , Clerkenwell</name>
        <terminalName>001023</terminalName>
        <lat>51.52916347</lat>
        <long>-0.109970527</long>
        <installed>true</installed>
        <locked>false</locked>
        <installDate>1278947280000</installDate>
        <removalDate/>
        <temporary>false</temporary>
        <nbBikes>12</nbBikes>
        <nbEmptyDocks>7</nbEmptyDocks>
        <nbDocks>19</nbDocks>
    </station>

    ... more...

    <station>
        <id>260</id>
        <name>Broadwick Street, Soho</name>
        <terminalName>003489</terminalName>
        <lat>51.5136846</lat>
        <long>-0.135580879</long>
        <installed>true</installed>
        <locked>false</locked>
        <installDate>1279711020000</installDate>
        <removalDate/>
        <temporary>false</temporary>
        <nbBikes>12</nbBikes>
        <nbEmptyDocks>4</nbEmptyDocks>
        <nbDocks>18</nbDocks>
    </station>

    ...

 </stations>
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Right now I have an NSDictionary with one object and one key - "stations", but I want the NSDictionary (or NSArray) of NSDictionarys.

I'm using an XML parser by Troy Brant - http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

I'm guessing it's going to involve some looping of some sort but I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use the XMLReader it is very easy to understand  
I have looked at your xml, and I am assuming you wanted to use the array of station tags.  
Here is my solution:

```
NSDictionary *dictXML= [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
NSArray *arrStation = [[dictXML objectForKey:@"stations"] objectForKey:@"station"];//this would return the array of station dictionaries
```

Now that you have the array of station tags you can do what you want for example displaying all id:

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrStation count];i++){
   NSDictionary *aStation = [arrStation objectAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"id = %@",[aStation objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

also you can write less code using the fast enumeration loop:

```
for(NSDictionary *aStation in arrStation){
  NSLog(@"id = %@",[aStation objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: Fantastic answer thanks, didn't know that [[dictXML objectForKey:@"stations"] objectForKey:@"station"]; would return an array with multiple entries! Thanks again.

Comment: from the code.. if you `NSLog(dictXML)` you would see that its a dictionary named **stations** and inside of it is another dictionary named **station** which contains the array of dictionaries.. the rule of XMLReader is when ever  a tag has been repeated it will create an array of it and it is a dictionary with the key of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create subclasses of `NSObject` that map to each tag. That would be way more cleaner than using Dictionaries and Arrays.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right, using CoreData right? How do I actually do the mapping of XML data to CoreData?

Comment: @AdamWaite If you are going to store the information then yes you should use Core Data, first design the Database and use the wizard to automatically create the classes for you. Then you can use the nsmanagedobject to create new instances and set the values. Otherwise if you aren't going to store it for long simply create the classes yourself.